# USB works only when booting in recovery mode

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit installed on my HP Pavilion Windows Tablet with an Intel® Core™ i3-4030U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4. When I've booted Ubuntu, my USB mouse does not work. The laser is lighting during the boot process, but when the login screen appears, it goes out. I figured that it's apparently a problem with the USB devices as when I plug in my USB stick, the drive does not appear and I have only sda's in my /dev/ folder. Usually I have to reboot several times for the USB devices to work. What could cause this problem?

Here is what `lsusb` outputs when the USB ports don't work:

```
stefan@stefan-HP-Pavilion-13-x360-PC:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I restarted the system and now the USB works. Here `lsusb`'s output:

```
stefan@stefan-HP-Pavilion-13-x360-PC:~$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2537:1081  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0cf3:3121 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 048d:8350 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 06cb:114f Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c01e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

On Bus 003 Device 002 the blank line is for an USB memory device. On Bus 002 Device 002 we have the Optical Mouse.

**Edit:** I discovered that the USB works every time I start the system by first booting the recovery mode in GRUB, then selecting "resume" in the menu. But USB never works when I start the system regularly.

Here is the output of dmesg | grep usb with USB working after booting normally:

```
[    0.910332] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.910340] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.910364] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    3.794041] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    3.794043] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    3.794046] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    3.794048] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-59-generic ehci_hcd
[    3.794049] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    3.794635] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    3.794637] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    3.794639] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    3.794641] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-59-generic xhci_hcd
[    3.794643] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    3.796767] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    3.796769] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    3.796771] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    3.796773] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-59-generic xhci_hcd
[    3.796775] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    4.105972] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    4.238361] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    4.238363] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    4.405876] usb 2-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    4.427930] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c01e
[    4.427932] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.427933] usb 2-2: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
[    4.427934] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    4.428045] usb 2-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    4.436719] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    4.436719] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    4.438179] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input6
[    4.438300] hid-generic 0003:046D:C01E.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[    4.593843] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    4.691064] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b40e
[    4.691066] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    4.691067] usb 2-3: Product: HP Truevision HD
[    4.691068] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd.
[    4.809743] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    4.827199] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=06cb, idProduct=114f
[    4.827201] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.827203] usb 2-4: Product: Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04
[    4.827204] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: SYNAPTICS
[    4.993674] usb 2-5: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    5.023015] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=048d, idProduct=8350
[    5.023017] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.023018] usb 2-5: Product: ITE Device(8350)
[    5.023019] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: ITE Tech. Inc.
[    5.233616] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    5.250957] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121
[    5.250959] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    6.632578] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    6.691571] input: SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input10
[    6.691939] input: SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input11
[    6.692311] hid-multitouch 0003:06CB:114F.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[    6.747731] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 6
[    6.747789] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[    6.835002] input: HP Truevision HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/input/input13
[    6.835160] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    7.020878] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   12.019093] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 183 at /build/linux-kDCE9u/linux-3.13.0/drivers/usb/host/xhci-ring.c:1581 handle_cmd_completion+0xe36/0xe40()
[   12.019095] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep dm_crypt nls_iso8859_1 hid_sensor_accel_3d intel_rapl snd_hda_codec_realtek hid_sensor_magn_3d x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp hid_sensor_gyro_3d coretemp arc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer ath9k kfifo_buf kvm snd_hda_intel ath9k_common industrialio hp_wmi hid_sensor_iio_common sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec ath9k_hw snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_pcm snd_page_alloc ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo ath aesni_intel snd_rawmidi aes_x86_64 lrw snd_seq gf128mul glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc ablk_helper cryptd mac80211 videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core videodev hid_multitouch hid_sensor_hub cfg80211 snd_seq_device snd_timer joydev ath3k serio_raw btusb rtsx_pci_ms memstick lpc_ich bluetooth snd hp_accel parport_pc lis3lv02d mei_me soundcore ppdev hp_wireless input_polldev shpchp mei lp intel_smartconnect mac_hid parport hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 psmouse i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper ahci drm r8169 libahci mii rtsx_pci wmi video
[   12.223048] usb 2-7: Device not responding to set address.
[   12.426899] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[   12.538913] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[   12.557106] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121
[   12.557112] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Here is the output when USB ceased to work after restarting the system

```
[    0.854276] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.854285] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.854309] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.598769] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.598772] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.598774] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.598776] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-59-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.598778] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.599376] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.599378] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.599380] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.599382] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-59-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.599384] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.601533] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.601535] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.601537] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.601539] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-59-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.601541] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.910642] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    2.046848] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    2.046850] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.214575] usb 2-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.236207] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c01e
[    2.236209] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.236211] usb 2-2: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
[    2.236212] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.236375] usb 2-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    2.245401] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.245402] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.246985] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input6
[    2.247108] hid-generic 0003:046D:C01E.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[    2.402537] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.499753] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b40e
[    2.499755] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.499756] usb 2-3: Product: HP Truevision HD
[    2.499757] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd.
[    2.618488] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.636041] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=06cb, idProduct=114f
[    2.636043] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.636044] usb 2-4: Product: Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04
[    2.636045] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: SYNAPTICS
[    2.750399] usb 2-5: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.780909] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=048d, idProduct=8350
[    2.780912] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.780913] usb 2-5: Product: ITE Device(8350)
[    2.780914] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: ITE Tech. Inc.
[    2.990354] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    3.007730] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121
[    3.007732] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    4.248978] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    4.272245] input: SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input9
[    4.276234] input: SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input10
[    4.276423] hid-multitouch 0003:06CB:114F.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[    4.309419] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[    4.309432] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 6
[    4.333707] input: HP Truevision HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/input/input13
[    4.333865] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.589670] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    9.587952] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at /build/linux-kDCE9u/linux-3.13.0/drivers/usb/host/xhci-ring.c:1581 handle_cmd_completion+0xe36/0xe40()
[    9.587954] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep dm_crypt nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek hid_sensor_gyro_3d snd_hda_intel hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_magn_3d snd_hda_codec hid_sensor_trigger snd_hwdep intel_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer x86_pkg_temp_thermal kfifo_buf intel_powerclamp snd_pcm industrialio hid_sensor_iio_common coretemp snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm hp_wmi sparse_keymap snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq arc4 aesni_intel ath9k aes_x86_64 lrw snd_seq_device gf128mul glue_helper ath9k_common ablk_helper snd_timer cryptd ath9k_hw uvcvideo joydev ath3k ath hid_multitouch mac80211 hid_sensor_hub serio_raw videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core cfg80211 videodev bluetooth rtsx_pci_ms lpc_ich memstick snd parport_pc hp_accel soundcore lis3lv02d ppdev mei_me input_polldev shpchp mac_hid mei lp intel_smartconnect hp_wireless parport hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 i2c_algo_bit psmouse drm_kms_helper ahci drm r8169 libahci mii rtsx_pci wmi video
[    9.792000] usb 2-7: Device not responding to set address.
[    9.995757] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[   10.107754] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[   10.125192] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121
[   10.125197] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[   10.591610] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   10.619842] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   10.647861] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   10.700509] usb 2-5: USB disconnect, device number 5
[   10.700991] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 8
```

After restarting Ubuntu in recovery mode, USB works. Here's the output:

```
[    0.884428] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.884437] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.884462] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.638202] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.639480] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.640747] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.642026] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-59-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.643272] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.655741] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.656901] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.658054] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.659203] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-59-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.660354] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.668136] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.669240] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.670314] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.671369] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-59-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.672422] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.960858] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    2.093122] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    2.094075] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.264746] usb 2-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.286279] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c01e
[    2.287263] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.288227] usb 2-2: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
[    2.289194] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.290310] usb 2-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    2.301380] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.302413] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.304957] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input6
[    2.306205] hid-generic 0003:046D:C01E.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[    2.456657] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.553960] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b40e
[    2.555002] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.556009] usb 2-3: Product: HP Truevision HD
[    2.557020] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd.
[    2.676604] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.693954] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=06cb, idProduct=114f
[    2.694975] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.695971] usb 2-4: Product: Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04
[    2.696972] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: SYNAPTICS
[    2.864508] usb 2-5: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.896486] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=048d, idProduct=8350
[    2.897568] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.898633] usb 2-5: Product: ITE Device(8350)
[    2.899701] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: ITE Tech. Inc.
[    3.056439] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    3.073833] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121
[    3.074931] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.763593] input: SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input9
[    3.766561] input: SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input10
[    3.777290] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    3.789046] hid-multitouch 0003:06CB:114F.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[    3.823754] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 6
[    3.823774] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[    3.887549] input: HP Truevision HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/input/input12
[    3.895447] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    3.910897] Modules linked in: coretemp(+) snd_hda_intel(+) snd_hda_codec kvm_intel(-) snd_hwdep ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath kvm snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul uvcvideo crc32_pclmul mac80211 videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops ghash_clmulni_intel videobuf2_core snd_page_alloc aesni_intel ath3k aes_x86_64 snd_seq_midi videodev lrw snd_seq_midi_event gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper hid_sensor_hub cryptd btusb hid_multitouch snd_rawmidi cfg80211 rtsx_pci_ms bluetooth joydev snd_seq serio_raw lpc_ich memstick snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_smartconnect hp_wireless hp_accel lis3lv02d shpchp input_polldev mei_me soundcore mei mac_hid hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 psmouse i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper ahci r8169 drm libahci mii rtsx_pci wmi video
[    4.116086] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    9.114253] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 51 at /build/linux-kDCE9u/linux-3.13.0/drivers/usb/host/xhci-ring.c:1581 handle_cmd_completion+0xe36/0xe40()
[    9.114258] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep dm_crypt nls_iso8859_1 parport_pc ppdev lp parport hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf industrialio hid_sensor_iio_common snd_hda_codec_realtek arc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp ath9k coretemp snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath kvm snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul uvcvideo crc32_pclmul mac80211 videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops ghash_clmulni_intel videobuf2_core snd_page_alloc aesni_intel ath3k aes_x86_64 snd_seq_midi videodev lrw snd_seq_midi_event gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper hid_sensor_hub cryptd btusb hid_multitouch snd_rawmidi cfg80211 rtsx_pci_ms bluetooth joydev snd_seq serio_raw lpc_ich memstick snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_smartconnect hp_wireless hp_accel lis3lv02d shpchp input_polldev mei_me soundcore mei mac_hid hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 psmouse i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper ahci r8169 drm libahci mii rtsx_pci wmi video
[    9.114755]  [<ffffffff81549434>] ? usb_control_msg+0xd4/0x110
[    9.318229] usb 2-7: Device not responding to set address.
[    9.522068] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[    9.634056] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    9.651330] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121
[    9.651335] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[   65.649272] usb 3-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   65.665515] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2537, idProduct=1081
[   65.665522] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   65.665525] usb 3-1: Product: USB Flash Disk
[   65.665527] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: General
[   65.665529] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 0169000000000307
[   65.688454] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   65.693406] scsi4 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[   65.693775] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
```

**Edit (08/25/15)**: I discovered some interesting phenomenon. Whenever I boot Windows 8 (where the USB never causes any problems), then I reboot and select Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, it suddenly works. How can a functioning USB under Windows cause it to work properly after rebooting into Ubuntu?

Comment: Excessive dust in the port, a shorting USB extension cable, a flaky chipset, operator error, the list goes on and on. Has anything that you've tried altered the results? If so, [edit] your question and let us know that along with anything else you think we might need to know like whether or not you are using an external USB hub, whether the devices are less or more reliable when attached to a different system, the output from the command `lsusb` before and after plugging in the mouse and or before and after plugging in the flash drive.

Comment: output of 
dmesg |grep usb
might be helpfull (both cases)

Comment: Did you try using any other mouse?

Comment: @kashminder: Yes, I did, the same problem. Note that the problem affects all USB devices, not just the mouse. It either works entirely, so that I can use my mouse and mount USB sticks, or USB devices are not recognized at all.

Comment: Boot to recovery, run lsmod > mods.recovery , reboot run lsmod > mods.regular. Compare contents of mods.recovery and mods.regular, see if there's any modules present in recovery but not in regular boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem got kind of resolved by changing to the latest Ubuntu version (15.10 *Wily*). I also removed Windows from my laptop when I installed Wily, so this is now a single-boot system, if this was in any way related to the problem. In Ubuntu Wily I haven't discovered any problems so far.